# Inbound Channel Adapter - Java / Annotation based configuration to start / stop using control bus

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-integration

In my application, there is need to start the inbound channel adapter message consumption. I came across xml based configuration but I am looking for Spring integration with Annotation or Java configuration to start / stop inbound channel adapter.

Can someone point out on how to do it ?

Comment: not sure what is the downvote for, with this, I will never be able to comment or vote before I reach count of 15 :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, please: [Spring Integration how to use Control Bus with JavaConfig, no DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63145799/2756547). That answer is related to your concern.

What you should do with your configuration is an `@EndpointId` alongside with the `@InboundChannelAdapter` in your Java config.

Comment: Thanks, Artem. yes,@EndPointId is useful in order to get handle to inbound channel adapter, is there a better way to add shutdown hook to stop the inbound channel adapter ? One way is when there is no more message.

Comment: That’s different story and leads to different direction. Anyway try to see how `MesaageSourceAdvice` can help you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/index-single.html#conditional-pollers